# Geotagging with PhotoCaptureDevice in WP8

Tags: geolocation, gps, photo, exif, windows-phone-8

I took a look on the new "PhotoCaptureDevice" and related classes in Windows Phone 8 but could not find means to add location data to captured images (GPS location).
Are there means to add such information in Windows Phone 8? Or is this only possible with the built-in camera?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to write the EXIF location data manually before sending the image stream (memory stream) to the media gallery.

Answer (score 0):

`Extensions.SaveJpeg()` saves `Exif geolocation` data automatically if `ID_CAP_LOCATION` is enabled.
I have not tried the new `WP8` classes yet, but it is quite likely they behave in the same way.

Comment: Yes, it's the same with WP8 but there are no means to control this other than manually removing the EXIF location if you don't want to store it.